# ¿Como puedo remplazar MariaDB por Mysql en XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

¡Hola a todos!, mi problema es que cuando exporto mi modelo relacional de workbench a formato sql en phpmyadmin me dice error de sintaxis a la hora de importarlo, estuve leyendo que me da error porque xampp por defecto instala MariaDB y yo lo estoy haciendo con MySQL (realmente no se si esto tenga algo que ver). Aqui dejo una foto del error que me da mi archivo sql generado por workbech y de mi EER [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MI CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE**

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Sun Jun 28 13:24:14 2020
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema punto_venta
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema punto_venta
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `punto_venta` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Producto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Producto` (
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Costo_provedor` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Precio_Venta` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Marca` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad_unitaria` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Rol`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Rol` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Nombre_UNIQUE` (`Nombre` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Empleado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Empleado` (
  `Usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Contraseña` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `FechaNacimiento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo_Postal` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Salario` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `id_Rol` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Usuario`),
  INDEX `FK_EMP_ROL_idx` (`id_Rol` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EMP_ROL`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Rol`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Rol` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Sucursal`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Sucursal` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Ciudad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Codigo_Postal` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_Empleado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_SUC_EMP_idx` (`id_Empleado` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SUC_EMP`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Empleado`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Empleado` (`Usuario`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Inventario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Inventario` (
  `Existencia` INT NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIME,
  `Estado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Precio_Venta` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `idProducto` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_Sucursal` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`, `id_Sucursal`),
  INDEX `FK_4_idx` (`idProducto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_INV_SUC_idx` (`id_Sucursal` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INV_PRODUC`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProducto`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INV_SUC`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Sucursal`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Sucursal` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Venta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Venta` (
  `idVenta` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Total` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVenta`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Detalle_Venta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Detalle_Venta` (
  `Precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `unidades` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Id_Venta` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_sucursal` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Venta`, `id_producto`, `id_sucursal`),
  INDEX `FK_2_idx` (`Id_Venta` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_VEN_SUC_idx` (`id_sucursal` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_VEN_VENTA`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Venta`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Venta` (`idVenta`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_VEN_PRODUC`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_VEN_SUC`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_sucursal`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Sucursal` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `punto_venta`.`Sucursal_Empleado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punto_venta`.`Sucursal_Empleado` (
  `id_Sucursal` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_Empleado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_Sucursal`, `id_Empleado`),
  INDEX `FK_SUC_INTER_EMP_idx` (`id_Empleado` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SUC_INTER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Sucursal`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Sucursal` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SUC_INTER_EMP`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Empleado`)
    REFERENCES `punto_venta`.`Empleado` (`Usuario`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Listo, ¡ahora añadí mi código!, la verdad no se en que podría estar mal. Si pudiera alguien ayudarme con eso se lo agradecería mucho :)

Comment: ¡Listo!, ese es mi código :)

Comment: Solo reemplaza `SCHEMA` por `DATABASE` y elimina todos los `VISIBLE`. Con eso debe importar correctamente.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, voy a probar en phpmyadmin